# How to select desired data frames from several data frames based on row id

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have a set of 7 random samples with 6 rows each in a data frame. The row id of the data range from 1 to 10. I need a code that will screen the 7 samples and return ONLY the data frames without any of row id 3, 7 or 10. This means that any of the samples containing one or more of 3, 7 or 10 must not be returned. Please how can I do this?

Here is my data below;

```
df8 <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
  name =c("james","milos","abdul","rose","helen","ahmed","xian","obi","koffi","trump"),
  entry_date = as.Date(c("1991-1-20","1992-2-21","1993-3-23","1994-4-24","1995-5-25",
                    "1996-6-26","1997-7-27","1998-8-28","1999-9-29","2000-10-30"))
)

library(dplyr)
kk <- as.data.frame(replicate(7, sample_n(df8, 6, replace = FALSE), simplify = FALSE))
```

I have tried;

```
filter(kk, !(id == 3 | id == 7 | id == 10)
```

and it gave me
Error: unexpected symbol in:

```
"filter(kk, !(id == 3 | id == 7 | id == 10)
filter"`
```

Please, kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be better off with a list of data frames than a wide data frame. You can use `Filter` to remove dataframe if `any` of `id` is `%in% c(3, 7, 10)`:

```r
set.seed(13)
kk <- replicate(7, sample_n(df8, 6, replace = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)
Filter(\(x) !any(x$id %in% c(3, 7, 10)), kk)

[[1]]
  id  name entry_date
1  6 ahmed 1996-06-26
2  8   obi 1998-08-28
3  9 koffi 1999-09-29
4  5 helen 1995-05-25
5  1 james 1991-01-20
6  4  rose 1994-04-24
```

---

If you prefer the `tidyverse`, you can `bind_rows` and `filter`:

```r
library(dplyr) #You need dplyr 1.1.0 or above
bind_rows(kk, .id = "df") %>% 
  filter(!any(id %in% c(3, 7, 10)), .by = df)

  df id  name entry_date
1  4  6 ahmed 1996-06-26
2  4  8   obi 1998-08-28
3  4  9 koffi 1999-09-29
4  4  5 helen 1995-05-25
5  4  1 james 1991-01-20
6  4  4  rose 1994-04-24
```

Comment: Yes. Your answer was very helpful. I am glad it handled it well @Mael